# HTML/CSS nested ordered list

Tags: html, css

-I am trying to create the CSS for a sub sub sub ordered list.

-I would also like to indent each sub list.

-How does the styling work for each header, e.g. 1, 2 and 3

**HTML**

```
<ol>
  <li>Item
      <ol>
          <li>Item</li>
          <li>Item</li>
      </ol>
  </li>

  <li>Item          
       <ol>
          <li>Item</li>
          <li>Item
            <ol>
              <li>Item</li>
              <li>Item</li>
            </ol></li>
          <li>Item</li>
          <li>Item</li>
       </ol>
   </li>

   <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

**Output to be achieved**

```
1. Item
    1.1 Item
    2.2 Item

2. Item
    2.1 Item
    2.2 Item
      2.2.1 Item
      2.2.2 Item
    2.3 Item
    2.4 Item

3. Item
```

**CSS**

This is what I have got so far:

```
ol {
list-style-type: none;
counter-reset: item;
}

li:before {
content: counters(item, ".")". ";
counter-increment: item
}
```

Comment: You should have updated the question under update heading. With the current question, answer posted by me seems inappropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your css to following

```
ol { counter-reset: item }
li { display: block }
li:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

For reference - http://jsfiddle.net/f3adtsmb/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to give credit for being a useful answer but i haven't earned enough points yet!

Comment: Great it worked for you :)

Comment: What about if we would like to style the main header? 

E.g. 
1. Item

As <li> has been open, it styles the entire paragraph

Comment: Sorry did not you. Can you please re phrase it?

Comment: How can we style the header for each section, 1, 2, 3 without styling 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2

Comment: Do you mean style for header as 1, 2 and 3, and nothing for sub list elements?

Comment: Add a class to top most ol. Let us say class be "my_ol". Now change the style of ol to ol.my_ol and li:before to ol.my_ol > li:before. For reference - http://jsfiddle.net/f3adtsmb/1/

Comment: I added, 2.3 & 2.4 onto the html now and it does not continue!

Comment: You should move the ol in the second li. Here is the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/f3adtsmb/2/