# TinyMce nested ordered list decimal numbering with different numbering styles

Tags: html, css, tinymce-4

**Background**

The Tinymce editor supports nested numbered lists. Naturally something like this is possible with the editor,

[image]

Now the requirement is to show numbers like this,

[image]

**So far**

This is doable by modifying the stylesheet associated with the editor with following list styles (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356612/html-css-nested-ordered-list) answer)

```
ol { counter-reset: item }
li { display: block }
li:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```

**Question**

Now the issue is if I select some other number format (for example lower Greek from the editor it looks like following)

[image]

how do I get the nested lists also to use the same format as the parent list?

Comment: I have no experience with TinyMCE but if the nested list is numbered using CSS counters then you can set the format on the counter. I can show a plain CSS example if that would be sufficient for you.

Comment: Tinymce generates a list of ordered list, but it set only the parent format. So, if you can show me how to inherit parents format to the child counters, that should be good enough.

Comment: Actually if you set the format in that `counters()` function that you have shown in question, it would apply everywhere and there would be no need to inherit at all. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v8rL6gsz/) is a sample of what I mean.

Comment: I don't think it will work because I don't know the format, it should be the same as the value set to the parent list by the Tinymce editor. HTML  generated by editor looks like <ol style="list-style-type: lower-greek;"><li>One<ol><li>One - one</li><li>One - two</li></ol></li><li>Two<ol><li>Two - one</li><li>Two - two</li></ol></li></ol> and other lists are nested under this root ordered list element.

Comment: The format or the CSS property itself can be set via JS (inline styles) but I get your point. Need somebody with a better understanding of how TinyMCE works to give an answer. I'll leave my demo there just in case it helps somebody else :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution for the problem,

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item
}

ol li {
  display: block
}

ol li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") ". ";
  counter-increment: item
}

ol[style*="list-style-type: lower-alpha;"] li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".", lower-alpha) ". ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Level 1</li>
  <li>Level 1
    <ol>
      <li>Level 2</li>
      <li>Level 2</li>
      <li>Level 2
        <ol>
          <li>Level 3</li>
          <li>Level 3</li>
          <li>Level 3
            <ol>
              <li>Level 4</li>
              <li>Level 4</li>
              <li>Level 4</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Level 1</li>
  <li>Level 1</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I have been banging my head since one week. Was not getting an answer. Though I understand you answer here, I am not able to put that in my example. Would you mind to create a fiddle or paste entire code. That will really help me and save my job here... Thanks a lot in advance!!